# Azure Test in Web Chat: HTTP status code NotFound

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, botframework, azure-bot-service

I tried running a new code from Azure Pipelines into Azure Web App Bot, configured the application settings appropriately. Yet whenever I tried to test the service in the test chat web I got errors.


 Node version: 10.14.1

 botbuilder: 4.10.3

[Azure Repos + Azure Pipelines deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEwcc.png)

[Application Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEpkd.png)

[Test in Web Chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og0MM.png)

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzgqR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There was an error sending this message to your bot. HTTP status code: not found

To troubleshooting this issue, you could check the following points:

1.Navigate to `Settings` tab,  you need to make sure that the `Messaging endpoint` is `Https` instead of `Http`.

[image]

**Note:** It doesn't support the `Http` website.

2.Navigate to `Channels` tab, you could check if the Web Chat is in `Running` state without issues.

[image]

3.Navigate to `Configuation`, you need to make sure that the `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` do not change these after deploying the new code.

If it keeps getting errors, you can even consider creating a new web app bot to redeploy

[image]

On the other hand, this is [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/apps/devops-cicd-chatbot#build-pipeline) I refer to to deploy azure web app bot.

I deploy the new code to Azure App service with the `Azure App Service deploy` task.

**Result:**

[image]